# Windows 10 Pro x64 10586 won't run VS 2008 C# .exe's

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-10

Any standalone executable that was created by me in Visual Studio 2008 C# in the past won't run, either release or debug, in W10 build 10586. Creating a new executable shows the same symptoms. However, executing the debug in the IDE works fine. VS 2008 has the latest Service Pack. Everything worked in W10 build 10240. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Please report beta problems to Microsoft.

Comment: W10 build 10586 is released, not beta.

Comment: Hmm, no, 10586 was released as an Insider Preview 2 weeks ago.  "Insider" is a Microsoft word that really means "unpaid beta tester".  Also the basic reason why you don't see SO getting slammed with this problem, this would normally affect a great many programmers.

Comment: Meanwhile what is the errors logged in event viewer? That usually gives hints on what might be the cause.

Comment: I don't subscribe to Insider Builds. I am running the November update that was released to the public. I use Ultimate Windows Tweaker 4 to turn on the build number and that's how I derive the build number.

Comment: Anyway, I agree that this would would be a BIG problem if everyone was having this. I have determined that I have one executable that works in the location where I placed it, either double-clicking on it or via a shortcut in C:\Program Files (x86)\SerialDownloader, but if copy that same .exe to another location, it fails to execute. It looks like Explorer is being affected as well, because another instance is sometimes created in the Task Manager.

Comment: Something else is going on. Another person has the same symptoms on Windows 8.1. I need to investigate this more. Sorry for the false information.

Comment: Microsoft just pulled the entire November update. http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-yanks-latest-windows-10-release-from-its-download-server/

Answer (score 0):

I was Avast. Disabled the shields and it works.